# What is the fastest browser that can do page refresh?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I'm processing some files line by line and each line needs to be reloaded in the browser. So I have to reload more than 100k times.

I've tried Firefox and Chrome and seems that Firefox is faster and comsumes less resources, is there anything else that is like text based?

I know there was a browser called lynx, but anything else?

With Firefox it takes around 2 hours to do all 100k reloads.

Comment: Could you explain in a little more detail why you need to reload the file for each line, rather than just downloading the file one and iterating over it locally?

Comment: I'm using "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=temp.php" />" Using wamp server locally.